# Swift: How to get the size of an enum?

Tags: swift, enums

I have an enumeration like this:

```
enum SomeType: Int {
    case Base = 0
    case Expert = 1
    case Special = 2
}
```

What I'd like is to get the size of this enumeration, like this:

```
Int enumSize = sizeof(SomeType)
```

However, this leads to the unexpected result of "1"; what I'd like to have is "3", certainly ;-)

How may I achieve to get the 3 as result?

Thanks for your support!

- Hardy

Comment: `sizeof(SomeType) = 3` because 1 byte is used to store the enum values. What you seem to be looking for is the number of possible enumeration values.

Comment: Great, thanks - I didn't get that before...

Comment: ... and of course I meant `sizeof(SomeType) = 1` ...